# Reprojection problem with gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have a GeoTiff file with WGS84 datum projection and I'm trying to reproject it using gdalwarp. Using this command

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=tpers +azi=19 +tilt=30 +lon_0=-109.5 +lat_0=23 +h=1274199.4 +wktext' atnight.tif atnighttilted.tif
```

returns this

```
ERROR 1: Too many points (10000 out of 10000) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds.
```

I'm using GDAL version 1.10.0. This is the contents of the .tfw file:

```
0.0066667901
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-0.0066669136
-32.8672753199
72.8560317049
```

I've just started using gdalwarp.
Thanks in advance,
Tom

The output of `atnight.tif` using `gdalinfo` is:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: atnight.tif
       atnight.tfw
Size is 9123, 4957
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-32.870608714976186,72.859365161672642)
Pixel Size = (0.006666790125743,-0.006666913589395)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2012:11:26 15:13:57
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -32.8706087,  72.8593652) ( 32d52'14.19"W, 72d51'33.71"N)
Lower Left  ( -32.8706087,  39.8114745) ( 32d52'14.19"W, 39d48'41.31"N)
Upper Right (  27.9505176,  72.8593652) ( 27d57' 1.86"E, 72d51'33.71"N)
Lower Right (  27.9505176,  39.8114745) ( 27d57' 1.86"E, 39d48'41.31"N)
Center      (  -2.4600456,  56.3354198) (  2d27'36.16"W, 56d20' 7.51"N)
Band 1 Block=9123x115 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=9123x115 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=9123x115 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: you should define your -s_srs and check that the proj string for the tilted perspective is correct - are you sure +wktext needs to be appended to it?

Comment: what is the output of this:
`gdalinfo atnight.tif`
`gdalinfo atnighttilted.tif`

Comment: As an advance, using this command: `gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=tpers +azi=19 +tilt=30 +lon_0=-109.5 +lat_0=23 +h=1274199.4 +wktext' atnight.tif atnighttilt.tif` created a new file called `atnighttilt.tif` except it was exactly the same as atnight.tif

Comment: I think I need a much more thorough understanding of this tool and good information for beginners is difficult to find. Does anyone know of any good resources to get started with `gdalwarp`? Thanks

Comment: -s_srs represents the projstring/epsg code of your source data, i.e. atnight.tif. -t_srs should be the proj string for your target/destination file, i.e. atnighttilt.tif. In most cases it's best to define both with gdalwarp

Comment: I haven't worked with tilted perspective so I don't have a good mathematical feel for it. Based on Snyder's version though, I would try moving the center point in or near the raster's extents.

Comment: According to my answer in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160792/tilted-projection-in-qgis, tilted perspective will currently not work with gdalwarp.