# What is the proper syntax in gdal_translate to change image.png to a geotiff by assigning latlong pairs to pixels?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, coordinates, proj, gdal-translate, png

I cannot find comprehesible documentation on how to assign latlon to pixels in an orthogonal image that must be made into a proper geotiff.

```
INPUT kat.png (ORDINARY)  OUTPUT kat.tif (GEOTIFF)
512px by 512px 
corners are;  UL = lat +10 Lon -10 LR = Lat -10 Lon +10



gdal_translate 
-of Gtiff 
-a_ullr 0 0 512 512   
-a_srs '+proj=nsper +h=3000000000  +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84' 
-a_gt '0 0 -10 10   0 512 10 10 512 512 10 -10      512 0 -10 -10'
kat.png 
kat.tif
```

I have exhausted the documentation at gdal dot org and proj4 dot org. Bothering stkxchg is a last resort.

Comment: Should be OK as `gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -10 10 10 -10 -a_srs '+proj=nsper +h=3000000000  +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84' kat.png kat.tif`. -a_ullr and -a_gt cannot be used together, they are either-or. And you are totally lost with geotransformation. Maybe reading https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html helps. Your usage of `-a_gt` is not far from the correct usage of ground control points `-gcp`, though.

Comment: I already read the tutorial. I read 100% of ALL of the documentation at gdal dot org. The example given has no context. It is self referencing and there is no glossary.  For instance - (GT(0) x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the upper-left pixel.) the UL coordinate of ALL images is ALWAYS 0,0 What is GT(0) looking for? , What id ROW ROTATION ??? What is COL ROTATION?? there is NO explainatione . that is why I am here. There is no usable documentation. I READ ALL OF IT. thank you for your answer. Can you post a corrected translation?

Comment: Really? 100% of the documentation on GDAL.org, that's way more than I've read. I didn't have any problem with the GDAL_Translate documentation, it is brief but covers the basic facts. The -a_ullr does not rotate (warp) the image but it seems that's fine for your needs as the images are orthogonal and you only want to move-scale. As for -a_gt that's an expert usage as the 6 parameters are performing an affine transformation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation (more https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html#geotransforms-tut).

Comment: The UL corner (top left corner of the top left pixel) is indeed always 0,0 in image coordinate space (row, column), and GT(0) and GT(3) are used to express what are the coordinates in the georeferenced coordinate space (projected or geographic coordinates). The tutorial is not perfect but it is in the GitHub and it can be improved. The term "rotation" is IMHO  misleading but it is copied from ESRI https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-what-is-the-format-of-the-world-file-used-for-geore-000002860. See better explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file.

Comment: Yes Mike, 100%. I didn't come here after ten minutes of research. I come here looking for someone with a deep understanding of the software and is skilled enough to convey understanding. I've found neither yet, wish me luck. "If you can't teach it, you never understood it. " -- Richard Feynman

Comment: If you have just a few images, you can use QGIS 3 and load a plugin Freehand Raster Georeferencer. If you have a bunch you can use code like Python osgeo import gdal.  Do you want to use GDAL?

Comment: Thank you Cary, but this is part of a much larger project that will be automated and only command line operations can do that. Are you an expert in the GDAL tools suite? I have many questions regarding syntax that are not ddressed anywhere in the official documentation. -- Molly

Comment: Did setting the ullr coordinated work for you in this certain case? If it worked you can write it as an answer. You can suggest improvements to GDAL documentation by creating pull requests. For example I suppose that you understand the geotransform now so you know how to make the corresponding tutorial better.

Comment: I am no expert but have done this several times.  If I run into trouble, I will make a world file .tfw that has the pixel width and the upper left corner coords.  https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/204174165-TFW-World-File-Values  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61028/reprojection-problem-with-gdalwarp then use GDAL waro to make the proper geotiff

Comment: thank you user30184, I can set the corners to proper latlon but still have no idea how to pin arbitrary pixels to "ground control points".
```

gdal_translate 
-of Gtiff 
-a_ullr -1666666 1666666 1666666 -1666666  
-a_srs 
 "+proj=ortho  
 +ellps=WGS84 
 +datum=WGS84 
 +lat_0=85 
 +lon_0=45"  
kat.png 
QQQQ-kat-ortho.tif 
```

Comment: You can add as many ground control points as needed by adding `-gcp` parameters. I do not know how to explain the syntax better than in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-gcp `-gcp <pixel> <line> <easting> <northing> [<elevation>]`. Pixel (left to right) and line (top to bottom) mean offsets of pixels from the top left corner. The last two numbers are the georeferenced coordinates of that pixel, in order easting or longitude - northing or latitude. See this tutorial 
https://kokoalberti.com/articles/georeferencing-and-digitizing-old-maps-with-gdal/

Comment: I have not tried the -gcp options yet either.  Thanks @user30184 !  I am watching this tutorial to see what type of data is in <pixel>  is that 2 integers  like (150,350)?.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9iB27RWOTg

Comment: They are defined to be doubles in the GDAL documentation gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#_CPPv48GDAL_GCP but most often user gives them as integers because it is difficult to define locations as fractional pixels. Not impossible, though, for example in a place on an aerial photo where long straight ditches are crossing.